# Fundamental exponential derivative problem

Tags: calculus

I know the formula:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{u}=e^{u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
but I don't know how to sovle this problem:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{z},\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{x+y}$$

Comment: 1. Is $y$ dependent variable or independent variable? That is, is $y$ somehow depends on $x$ or is it a constant?(Is $y=f(x)$?) 2. Is  $y$ a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(e^{f(x)}\right)=f'(x)e^{f(x)},$$

Where $f'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$. We therefore have in the case that $z\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant, then we get:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(e^{z}\right)=0e^{z}=0,$$

Because there is no dependence of $z$ on $x$, and therefore $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$. For the second one we have:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(e^{x+y}\right)=1e^{x+y}=e^{x+y}$$

Because $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x+y\right)=1$.

I hope this helps clarify!

Comment: @Esteban I also answer it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x+y})=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x}\cdot e^{y})=e^{y}\frac{d}{dx}(e^{x})=e^{y}\cdot e^{x}=e^{x+y}
$$

Comment: @Esteban Thank you??

Comment: You seem to be assuming $y$ a constant. This _could_ be the reason someone downvoted. Since the question doesn't mention anything, it is the OP's error, not yours. So the downvote is unjustified. '+1'.

Comment: @user31782 Thanks but serial downvotes are not common. Maybe I should use partial derivative instead of ordinary derivative notation

Comment: It looks like OP meant to ask for the total derivative. It is a bit unusual to assume $y$ constant. BUT that's not a mistake! . The question itself is in the Grey Area. Looking at the [timeline](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/760383/timeline), it seems this downvoted is by the same troll who serialy downoted your posts(only your answer is downvoted on this page).